# In Javascript, is their a way to inspect an objects methods and attributes such as Python's dir()?

Tags: javascript, object, inspect

In Javascript is their a way to inspect an objects methods and attributes such as Python's dir() ?

```
dir(object) returns

object.height
object.width
object.compute_days_till_birthday()

etc.....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebug had a similar function

```
console.dir(obj)
```

Or you can do one yourself

```
var dir = '';
for (var i in obj) dir += 'obj[' + i + '] = ' + obj[i];
alert(dir);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can use a `for..in` loop (section 12.6.4 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)), which loops through the enumerable properties of both the object and its prototype (if it has one), like so:

```
var name;
for (name in obj) {
    // `name` is each of the property names, as a string; get the value
    // from obj[name]
    alert(name + "=" + obj[name]);
}
```

If you want to differentiate whether it's the object itself or its prototype that has the property, you can use [`obj.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
var name;
for (name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
       // `name` is the name of a property this object has for itself
    }
    else {
       // `name` is the name of a property the object inherits
       // from its prototype
    }
}
```

If you're using an implementation that supports some of the new [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) stuff, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of all of its enumerable property names, but really that's just an array version of what `for..in` gives you (and `for..in` is supported by every implementation of JavaScript I've ever seen or you're likely to).

When I say an "enumerable" property: Most of the built-in properties of objects defined by the specification (like `length` on `Array` instances, or `getTime` on `Date` instances) are *non-enumerable* and don't show up in the list. Until the 5th edition of the spec, there was no standard way to define your *own* non-enumerable property, but as of the latest you can do that via `Object.defineProperty` / `Object.defineProperties` (sections 15.2.3.6 and 12.2.3.7 of the spec). That's not widely-supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( var prop in obj ) {
   console.log( prop + ' is ' + obj[prop] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Chrome's console. If you log any sort of variable to it using `console.log()`, it lets you explore all of its methods and properties, including the prototype chain. This looks sort of like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has the `for .. in` loop construct to help with this:

```
for (var name in some_object) {
    // some_object[name] is the value of the property
}
```

However, there are some pitfalls with this approach:

1. An object property can be of *any* type. If you need to filter the list you retrieve, you will need to use `typeof`.
2. `for .. in` will iterate over properties pulled out from the target object's prototype chain. If you want to process only properties defined on the target object itself, you should additionally test for `some_object.hasOwnProperty(name)`.